# Do Klingons believe that William Shakespeare was Klingon?

Tags: star-trek, klingon, shakespeare

From Wikipedia <sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Klingon_Hamlet)</sup> :

> In a scene from the film Star Trek VI a dinner is held for the Klingon
>   chancellor, Gorkon. He makes a toast to "the undiscovered
>   country...the future". Spock, recognizing the quotation, responds,
>   "Hamlet, Act 3 Scene 1", to which Gorkon *replies with his statement
>   about the "original" Klingon text of Shakespeare.* Though Gorkon does
>   not quote from the "original" Klingon text, another character, Chang
>   quotes the Klingon words "taH pagh taHbe'" (To be, or not to be). The
>   film is filled with other quotations and references to Shakespeare

Was the "original" Klingon text mentioned by Gorkon implying that Shakespeare was Klingon?

Comment: I recall something in a novel but I haven't seen anything on the screen

Comment: After all, this predilection is hardly unique to Klingons: https://www.google.com/amp/redshirtsalwaysdie.com/2016/07/24/video-chekov-claiming-things-were-invented-in-russia/amp/